# CSS: <li> items having 3 inline-block elements, last occupying max space

Tags: css, position, html-lists, anchor

In each list item in an unordered list I have 2 inline-block elements and an anchor text, all next to each other. So in each `<li>` there are 2 icons and a text.

The reason I made those 2 icons `display:inline-block` is because they have different heights and the anchor text next to them can occasionally become multiple lines, and I'm able to center them to the first line by the `vertical-align` rule.

Anyway this anchor tag has a `:hover` style, which is basically `background-color:gray`. For some reason I couldn't succeed in blocking this anchor element by any generic solution.

What I did sort of works but I can't rely on this solution because I'm using hard-coded with for the `<ul>` and `<a>` widths and when the list needs scrollbars these widths need to be subtracted the bar width. Below is my current solution, if that sheds a light to someone.

I tried giving the anchor text a margin-left and set it to `display:absolut`, to no avail. I also tried giving percentages but again… Ultimately I tried floating the elements but it's probably the wrongest solution here because of the multiline possibility of the text and centering each element in vertical center of the first line of the text. My next guess is using a table in each list item but that's probably the dirtiest solution available, and I don't want to use that unless I have to.

How would you do it? Let me know if you need further details.

#### CSS

```
ul {
    overflow:auto;
    height:6em;
    width:320px;
}
li .icon1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:13px;
    height:12px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:url(image.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
li .icon2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:9px;
    height:10px;
    margin-right:2px;
    background:url(image.jpg) left -12px no-repeat;
}
li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:4px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:270px;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="icon1"></div>
        <div class="icon2"></div>
        <a href="#">Some anchor text</a>
    </li>
    <!-- many other li items in here -->
</ul>
```

Here's an image to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: a pseudo image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You made a typo and missed a "g" in your `background-color` property. Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but it seemed to work as you intended after the typo was corrected.

Comment: @mdepolli That's because I just wrote the pseudo code here in SO. My real code is much more complicated.

Comment: OK, in that case I really don't understand what you meant by 'blocking this anchor element'. Do you want to have it occupy the entire width of the `<li>` containing element?

Comment: @mdepolli entire width minus the space occupied by those 2 icons. So practically `100% - 24px`

Answer (score 2):

The best two solutions I could think of where:
1) using the example below
CSS:

```
ul {
    overflow:auto;
    height:6em;
    width:320px;
}
.icon1 {
    width:13px;
    height:12px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:url(image.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.icon2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:9px;
    height:10px;
    margin-right:2px;
    background:url(image.jpg) left -12px no-repeat;
}
li a {
    display:block;
    padding-left:4px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="icon1" src="image.jpg" alt="icon1"/><img class="icon2" src="image.jpg" alt="icon2"/>Some label in here!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="icon1" src="image.jpg" alt="icon1"/><img class="icon2" src="image.jpg" alt="icon2"/>Some label in herdsafasdfasdfsad sadfasd sadfasd asdfsade!</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

2) You could also add background images to the li items with:

```
background-image: url(image.jpg);
```

for the icons

Comment: Did you check the attached image?

Comment: Yes I did but I dont see any major differences between your image and the example

Comment: I can not know the native scrollbar width(s) so I can not give rigid widths to the `<ul>` and `<a>` elements. When it fails to fit, the `<a>` tag naturally shifts below 2 icons, for example.

Comment: I know but as my rep is to low to comment on other peoples questions I had to do it this way.... no need to downvote me for trying to help.

Comment: Did my post solve your problem? If it did please mark it as solved.

Comment: Nope. Your CSS suggestion does not help, sorry. It shifts the anchor element to the next line, obviously, because it's setting the display to block. I have no idea why you gave those borders, though. As with your 2nd solution, I can't do that becasue one of these elements occasionally becomes a **separately** clickable element. Also, I don't want the hover style to be applied to these 2 icons.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to solve it. I'm pretty sure this is not the ideal solution but it seems to work without any problem (yet, in the browsers I tried).

If somebody has a better solution please let me know.

Here's the whole code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Another dirty (but better) solution</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
ul {
    overflow:auto;
    width:18em;
    height:6em;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {overflow:hidden;}
li .icons {
    float:left;
    margin:-0.1em 0;
}
li .icons .icon1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:13px;
    height:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:red;
}
li .icons .icon2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:9px;
    height:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:green;
    margin-bottom:1px; /* here's the dirty hack: (icon1.height-icon2.height) / 2 */
}
li a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:0 4px;
    margin-left:24px;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">Some link text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">Some other link text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">A longer link text here</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">Shrt lnk txt</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">Much much looooonger text in here</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icons"><div class="icon1"></div><div class="icon2"></div></div>
            <a href="#">Just another link text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```